# Create a nullable type dynamically

Tags: c#

I need to set the Type variable to be a nullable one. e.g.

```
public Type CreateNullable(Type type){
    if (type.IsValueType)
        return Nullable<type>;

    // Is already nullable
    return type;
}
```

I'm seeing as there are a finite amount of the ValueType, I figure I'll just create a Dictionary of all the value types as nullable, and the return that. But am keen to see if there's a smarter way.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: There aren't a finite number of value types. Structs are value types.

Answer (score 10):

```
public Type CreateNullable(Type type){
    if (type.IsValueType)
        return typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(type);

    // Is already nullable
    return type;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Answer provided by *Cory* looks fine, but I would add check to make sure `type` is not already `Nullable<T>`:

```
public Type CreateNullable(Type type){
    if (type.IsValueType && (!type.IsGenericType || type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(Nullable<>)))
        return typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(type);

    // Is already nullable
    return type;
}
```